# how to set comma seperted values in text box coming frm database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, dom, textbox

I am getting value of a column Tags
here is the value 
**hello,this,is,test**
I have to set it on a text box 
i am using code like this

```
var i = o.Tag;
        $('#tags_1').val(i);
```

**where o.Tag=hello,this,is,test**

But it is not setting up these  values in text box.
so how can i set these values in text box.

Browser doessn't showing any error.

Comment: Please share some more code. Like HTML and full jQuery code. Also try to check browser console to see any error is there? if yse let us know. Current question have very less amount of code and we are unable to help

Comment: `o.Tag  !==O.Tags`. So seems like TYPO mistake. check this:- https://prnt.sc/h8m8e3

Answer (score 0):

Using `selectize.js` plugin and `jqueryui` you can achieve this.

```js
var i="hello,this,is,test";
$('#tags_1').val(i);
$('#tags_1').selectize({
  delimiter: ',',
  persist: false,
  create: function(input) {
    return {
      value: input,
      text: input
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.6.14/selectize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.6.14/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" id="tags_1"  value="" />
```